# Parsing XML Storing into NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I am attempting to parse an XML and store the URL from one element of the XML into an NSArray.  Here is my code so far:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.316apps.com/LakesideDocs/podcasttrial.xml"];

   NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSError *error;
   GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData 
                                                          options:0 error:&error];

   NSArray *channels = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
   for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            


       NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
       for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

           NSString *articlePoint = [item valueForChild:@"link"];
           NSArray *linkarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:articlePoint, nil];

           NSLog(@"%@", linkarray);

       }

   }
```

For the NSLog I would expect:

```
TabBarSample[40191:fb03] (
    (
    "http://domain.com/image1.jpg"
 ),
(
"http://domain.com/image2.jpg"
)
)
```

But I get:

```
TabBarSample[40191:fb03] (
"http://domain.com/image1.jpg"
)
TabBarSample[40191:fb03] (
"http://domain.com/image2.jpg"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't resist posting a link to my automated XML parsing library. No recursiveness, keep it simple: http://ceasyxml.googlecode.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with every loop you create a new array:

```
 NSArray *linkarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:articlePoint, nil];
```

instead you want a NSMutableArray outside of the llop and add an object during every loop

```
   NSMutableArray *linkarray = [NSMutableArray array];
   NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
   for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

       NSString *articlePoint = [item valueForChild:@"link"];
       [linkarray addObject:articlePoint];

       NSLog(@"%@", linkarray);

   }
```

if the increasing array is confusing for you, you should put the NSLog after the for loop:

```
   NSMutableArray *linkarray = [NSMutableArray array];
   NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
   for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

       NSString *articlePoint = [item valueForChild:@"link"];
       [linkarray addObject:articlePoint];
   }

   NSLog(@"%@", linkarray);
   NSLog(@"count: %d", [linkarray count]);
```

Comment: That somewhat works.  I end up getting two different NSLogs now.  One with just the first "link" value URL and one that has both.  I also set up `NSLog(@"TheCountIs%i", [linkarray count]);` and the console returned:
TheCountIs1
TheCountIs2
Is this normal?

Comment: sure: in every step you are adding one object, so the count increases by one.